# React Admin : How to use bootstrap instead of Material Design?

Tags: react-admin

and first of all thank you for your amazing work.

The README file indicates that it is possible to use Bootstrap instead of Material Design, but I can’t find any documentation of how to implement it.

Does anybody has already done that ? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, we did not find the time to document the `ra-core` package properly yet, so you'll have to explore the source code for now. I doubt you'll find any example for doing this as the separation into two packages (`ra-core` and `ra-material-ui`) is quite recent.

Be aware that building a bootstrap version of `react-admin` will take a lot of time. You'll have to explore the `ra-material-ui` package and build a bootstrap version of every components.

Comment: By the way, may I ask why you'd like a bootstrap version ?

Comment: Thank you Gildas for your answer. 

The use of Bootstrap is a client (customer) request, and I was just wondering if using Bootstrap instead of material-ui was so easy. 

Fortunately you gave me a very useful answer :)

Comment: If you do try to make a `ra-ui-bootstrap` I'll be happy to help and fine tune the `ra-core` package where needed

Comment: So, @NicolasPotier would you like to develop `ra-ui-bootstrap`? :)

Comment: Hello @DiMoN_TD, I won't be able to do this. We decided to `keep ra-material-ui` instead of building a bootstrap version of `react-admin`

Comment: It would be great to see the docs updated and remove the following "It is very easy to replace one part of react-admin with your own, e.g. to use a custom datagrid, GraphQL instead of REST, or bootstrap instead of Material Design."

Assuming this thread is still accurate and that getting to bootstrap is not "easy" then I think it would be nice to update the docs and say just that.

Comment: Waiting for your pull request ;)